# C# - Remove all items from listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have a C# winform that uses a listbox with a bound list for the datasource. The list is created from a text file on the computer. I'm trying to create a "Remove all" button for this listbox and am having a little trouble.

First, here is the relevant code:

```
private void btnRemoveAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use a binding source to keep the listbox updated with all items
        // that we add
        BindingSource bindingSource = (BindingSource)listBox1.DataSource;

        // There doesn't seem to be a method for purging the entire source,
        // so going to try a workaround using the main list.
        List<string> copy_items = items;
        foreach (String item in copy_items)
        {
            bindingSource.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

I've tried foreaching the bindingSource, but it gives an enumeration error and just won't work. As far as I can tell, there's not code to just purge an entire source, so I tried going through the List itself and removing them via the item name, but that doesn't work either since the foreach actually returns an object or something and not a string.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the `Clear()` method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611667/how-to-remove-all-listbox-items(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611667/how-to-remove-all-listbox-items) , http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/ClearallitemsinaListBox.htm(http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/ClearallitemsinaListBox.htm) ,  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19698/How-to-Move-List-Box-Items-to-another-List-Box-in(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19698/How-to-Move-List-Box-Items-to-another-List-Box-in) ,and try this three articles...

Comment: @LightStriker, I have tried clear();

Comment: @lelyor all those links 404 for me for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bound the Listbox to a BindingSource using some generic List then you can just do this:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = (BindingSource)listBox1.DataSource;
IList SourceList = (IList)bindingSource.List;

SourceList.Clear();
```

On the other handy, holding a reference to the underlaying List in your Form, Viewmodel or whatever would do the trick aswell.

EDIT:
This only works if your List is a ObservableCollection. For normal List you can try call ResetBindings() on the BindingSource to enforce a refresh.

Comment: I just tried using the IList and clearing that and it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't give an error or anything, but doesn't clear anything for the list. Or rather, if it does, it doesn't update the listbox or the binding. Edit: It doesn't update the binding. Adding an item after hitting remove all shows only that item in the list.

Comment: Sorry, this will only work if the underlying List is a ObservableCollection. Do you get a IList back when accessing the List Property? Edit: The fact that you only see 1 Item after Clear() and adding a new Items shows that you indeed get a list :) Use a ObservableCollection instead of a regular list or try call ResetBindings() on the Bindinglist.

Comment: Thanks, ResetBindings() is what I needed!

Answer (score 14):

You can do it directly by typing

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```