# Filtering ListBox.ItemsSource with CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm pretty new to programming for Windows Phone and I'm having trouble editing data in ListBox.
I'm loading data from my XML file into a list, and displaying them in ListBox.
Each entry in my XML has a type attached to it. I want to make it so I can remove/add entries with certain types, by checking/unchecking certain CheckBoxes.

I found something like this:
[How to remove all ListBox items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611667/how-to-remove-all-listbox-items)

But it doesn't exactly suit my needs since I want only to delete part of ListBox items, and then possibly get it back by simply checking the checkbox again.
Also I don't want to add every entry manually since I already bound listbox with a list containing my XML entries.

I upload my XML like so:

`Activity.cs`:

```
namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
   public class Activity
   {
      public string Type { get; private set; }
      public string Description { get; private set; }

      public Activity(string type, string description)
      {
           Type = type;
           Description = description;
      }

      public static List<Activity> LoadActivities(XDocument doc)
      {
        return doc .Root
                   .Elements("Activity")
                   .Select(el => new Activity((string)el.Attribute("Type"),
                                            el.Value))
                   .ToList();
      }

      public static List<Activity> LoadActivities()
      {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (store.FileExists("Activities.xml"))
            {
                 using (var stream = store.OpenFile("Activities.xml",
                                                    FileMode.Open))
                 {
                     return LoadActivities(XDocument.Load(stream));
                 }
            }
        }
        // No user file... load the default activities
        return LoadActivities(XDocument.Load("Assets/Activities.xml"));

      }
   }
}
```

Here is my code for my page:

```
namespace ActivityManager
{
    public partial class PivotPage1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private List<Activity> activities;

        public void ActivityDisplay()
        {
            activities = Activity.LoadActivities();
            listBox1.ItemsSource = activities;
        }

        public PivotPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ActivityDisplay();
        }

        private void CookingCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ArtCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void LanguageCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ScienceCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void SportCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

And xaml for ListBox:

```
<ListBox Height="347" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,243,0,0" 
         Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" 
         SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" AllowDrop="False" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding activities}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Margin="10">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Activity}"/>
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Also here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Activities>
    <Activity Type="Cooking">
      Cook some Mexican food
    </Activity>
    <Activity Type="Art">
      Draw a picture
    </Activity>
    <Activity Type="Language">
      Learn 5 words in Polish you didn't know yet
    </Activity>
    <Activity Type="Science">
      Write a simple program in C
    </Activity>
    <Activity Type="Sport">
      Go to the gym
    </Activity>
  </Activities>
```

Can you help me? I'm pretty stuck and probably missing something obvious. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint in your checked event and  after FilterActivity Happend check the ItemsSource is not null and has objects in it

Comment: @verdesrobert Turns out that during checked events source is empty. After FilterActivity happens there are finally objects in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this way:
Create a list of filters.
Update the list of filters when checking/unchecking the checkboxes, and at each filter change update the List

```
private List<Activity> activities;

public void ActivityDisplay()
{
    activities = Activity.LoadActivities();
    FilterActivities();
}

public ObservableCollection<string> ActivityFilter = new ObservableCollection<string>();

private void FilterActivities()
{
    listbox1.ItemsSource = null; //sometimes it makes the difference;
    listBox1.ItemsSource = activities.Where(activity => ActivityFilter.Any(filter => filter == activity.Type) || ActivityFilter.Count == 0);

}

public PivotPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ActivityFilter.CollectionChanged += ActivityFilter_CollectionChanged;
    ActivityDisplay();
}

void ActivityFilter_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FilterActivities();
}

private void CookingCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ActivityFilter.Add("Cooking");
}

private void CookingCheck_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ActivityFilter.Remove("Cooking");
}

//Repeat the procedure for each checkbox
```

I found an issue in your ItemTemplate use this one

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Margin="10">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to use your code and repeated the procedure, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Is this one complete? Or is there some additional way I have to refresh listbox in order to display properly? Because as of now, the listbox seems to be unaffected no matter what I check/uncheck.

Comment: Sadly it didn't resolve the issue. However after looking into the code again I noticed that you deleted `listBox1.ItemsSource = activities;` from `public void ActivityDisplay` in your example. When I did the same the list of activities didn't load at all. Is it possible that there is a problem with `listBox1.ItemsSource = activities.Where(activity => ActivityFilter.Any(filter => filter == activity.Type) || ActivityFilter.Count == 0);` ?

Comment: @Tajgun92 I forgot to bind it at first check the edit

Comment: Now it binds properly again, but sadly the issue is not resolved on my end. Checkboxes still do not work for listbox. All that changing ItemTemplate did was removing the type from listboxes, leaving only description